# Saved images from Photoshop do not show up in folders until restart

Tags: memory, image-editing, adobe-photoshop, macos

I have a problem saving images from Photoshop CC. I usually shoot Camera Raw images, edit them and save them as JPEGs. Photoshop seems to save images normally - it takes about 2 seconds to complete the save. However, when I then try to find the saved JPEG in the appropriate folder, it does not show up there. Only after restarting the computer am I able to see these newly saved images.

I've tried saving to the computer or directly to a memory card  - the same problem persists. Not sure if the problem is Photoshop or my Mac, but I thought I'd try and ask here.

I'm running macOS Mojave, version 10.14.5. My hardware is MacBook Pro Retina (15") 2015 16Gb.